# Вычисление памяти, занимаемой программой в Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

В просторах сети много советов использовать `GetProcessMemoryInfo` из `psapi.h`. Я сделал работающий пример на Qt5/C++, вот часть кода:

```
void Dialog::PrintMemoryInfo() {
  HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmce;
  if (hProcess) {
    if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&pmce, sizeof(pmce))) {
      qDebug() << "PageFaultCount:" << pmce.PageFaultCount;
      qDebug() << "PeakWorkingSetSize:" << pmce.PeakWorkingSetSize;
      qDebug() << "WorkingSetSize:" << pmce.WorkingSetSize;
      qDebug() << "QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage:" << pmce.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
      qDebug() << "QuotaPagedPoolUsage:" << pmce.QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
      qDebug() << "QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage:" << pmce.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
      qDebug() << "QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage:" << pmce.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
      qDebug() << "PagefileUsage:" << pmce.PagefileUsage;
      qDebug() << "PeakPagefileUsage:" << pmce.PeakPagefileUsage;
      qDebug() << "PrivateUsage:" << pmce.PrivateUsage;
    }
  }
}
```

Получаю вот такой вывод:

```
PageFaultCount: 14558
PeakWorkingSetSize: 35176448
WorkingSetSize: 24408064
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 224408
QuotaPagedPoolUsage: 222664
QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 17784
QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 17648
PagefileUsage: 17682432
PeakPagefileUsage: 17682432
PrivateUsage: 17682432
```

А в "Диспетчере Задач" вижу совсем другую цифру: 7.6MБ

**Вопрос:** как мне программно получить эти 7.6MБ?

Comment: Ну там в байтах цифры... Просто переведи в мегабайт

Comment: @ori что конкретно из этого перевести, чтобы получилось 7.6МБ?

Comment: Именно 7.6 не получишь, там указывается выгружаемый пулл памяти, реальный размер смотри во вкладке подробности, WorkingSetSize вот отсюда.

Comment: В Диспетчере задач выводится значение `PrivateWorkingSet`.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa965225(v=vs.85)

Comment: Всем спасибо! Не показан способ вычисления, но оно того наверное и не стоит. Я посмотрел в Process Explorer, что при выделении/освобождении памяти в программе - мне достаточно смотреть `PrivateUsage`. Диспетчер Задач показывает не интересующую меня цифру. А в Мониторе Ресурсов нужная цифра есть.